# Javascript error on IE8 and IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm getting 'this.0.files.0' is null or not an object error on IE8 and IE9 and Chrome and Mozila don't throw any errors .

```
$(function()) {
    var fileType = ['txt' , 'csv' ];
    $('.input_file').find('input [type = "file" ]').live('change', function (e)) {
        $this = $(this) 
        var ext = $this.val() === " " ? " " : this.value.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
        if($this.val()) {
            $this.parent().find('label').text.($this[0].files[0].name)  
        }
    }
}
```

Im not sure why above code throws a javascript error 'this.0.files.0' is null or not an object

Comment: `$this = $(this)` is missing a semi-colon.

Comment: IE8 and 9 has no support for the HTML5 File API.

Comment: @TiesonT. http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/ . If it's missing anything, it's missing `var` to make it a local variable

Comment: apologies , semi-colon is there by mistake I forgot while wiriting code here.

Comment: Friend , please let me know if this is a trailing comma problem in IE wherein firefox and chrome simple ignores training commas and IE has issues with it, please suggest

Comment: @ronan I there's no trailing comma problem, but you do have a lot of missing/extra characters. You don't close the functions and function calls properly, and you close some too soon.

Comment: @ronan For example, `$(function()) {` should be `$(function() {`, and `.live('change', function (e)) {` should be `.live('change', function (e) {`

Comment: @ronan And your last 2 `}` should be `});`

Comment: @Ian
Thanks but why would it throw this.0.files.0' is null or not an object is null or not an object

Comment: @ronan Have you seen the answer that Musa posted? That should be why

Comment: @I dont understand the answer yet well as I have a limited experience with HTML5

Comment: @Ian 
Please let me know if I have to make this code work on IE8 and IE9 , should jquery be removed ? and only js be used ?

Comment: @ronan No not at all, the problem has nothing to do with jQuery - it has to do with the fact that IE8/9 doesn't support `.files`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IE < 10 has no support for the html5 fileapi, i.e. no `HTMLInputElement.FileList` you'll have to parse `HTMLInputElement.value` to get the file name.

Comment: Thanks Musa , 
Please let me know , how this is related with HTML5 as this is a jquery code and then how this needs to be handled ?

Comment: @ronan `$this[0].files` is an instance of a [FileList](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filelist), which is part of the html5 [FileApi](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). This api is not available in IE < 10, instead you can get the file name from the `$this[0].value` property or `$this.val()`

Answer (score 1):

To get the filename you can do:

`var filename = $this[0].files ? $this[0].files[0].name : $this[0].value.match(/[^\/\\]*$/)[0];`

or simply:

`$this[0].value.match(/[^\/\\]*$/)[0];`

Full code:

```
$(function()) {
    var fileType = ['txt' , 'csv' ];
    $('.input_file').find('input [type = "file" ]').live('change', function (e)) {
        $this = $(this) 
        var ext = $this.val() === " " ? " " : this.value.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
        if ($this.val()) {
            var filename = $this[0].files ? $this[0].files[0].name : $this[0].value.match(/[^\/\\]*$/)[0];
            $this.parent().find('label').text.($this[0].files[0].name);
        }
    }
}
```